# for loop echo inside another echo

Tags: php

I have a foreach to run

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    echo "<div class='$_Vr'">" ,$i,"</div>" <p> </p>;
}
```

and have a test value

```
if ($_Vr == 'dd'){
echo 'yes';
}else{
echo 'no';
}
```

I understand I can do this way to get what I want

```
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    echo "<div class='$_Vr'">" ,$i,"</div><p>"?> 

if ($_Vr == 'dd'){
echo 'yes';
}else{
echo 'no';
}

<?php </p>";  }?>
```

but I'd like to know if I can put another echo inside foreach ? like

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    echo "<div class='$_Vr'">" ,$i,"</div>" <p> " , test value here , "</p>;
}
```

Comment: Use ternary operator... and also you are asking for foreqch and your question shows the code for `for` loop, so It's unclear here

Comment: You have inconsistent quoting. Ah the joys of building HTML strings within PHP

Comment: He also has mismatched quotes, an extra `?>`, etc. The code is a mess that can't actually run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the conditional (AKA ternary) operator:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    echo "<div class='$_Vr'>$i</div> <p> " , ($_Vr == 'dd' ? "yes" : "no") , "</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    echo "<div class='$_Vr'>$i</div><p>".($_Vr == 'dd' ? 'yes': 'no')."</p>";
}
```

Comment: This is the solution you asked for, but I think you should think before using something like this.  Is this going to be code that others will look at?  You don't want to sacrifice readability for a little space savings.